# How do i get rid of designtime XAML error "Object reference not set to an instance of object" while setting datacontext

Tags: xaml, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext, design-time

I'm back again.

I'm getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of object" in my XAML designer when I add a design-time datacontext of my viewmodel.

[image]

I tried to debug with visual studio hoping to get some answers, but nothing shows up. Everything works fine, but I cannot rely on the fact if there is actually an error or not.

```
<Window x:Class="ISynergy.Views.Relations.Editors.ServicingProduct"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ISynergy.Views.Relations.Editors"
    xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:ISynergy.Controls;assembly=I-Synergy.Controls"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:ISynergy.Controls.Converters;assembly=I-Synergy.Controls" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ServicingProduct" Width="700" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ISynergy.Models.Relations.Editors;assembly=I-Synergy.Models" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModels:ServicingProduct_ViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Style="{DynamicResource StandardDialogWindow}">

<Grid Grid.Row="1" syncfusion:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Metro" syncfusion:SkinStorage.MetroBrush="{DynamicResource Foreground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Productcode:"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Artikel:" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Uitvoering:" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Merk/Fabrikaat:" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Type:" Grid.Row="9" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Serie:" Grid.Row="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Diepte (mm):" Grid.Row="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Breedte (mm):" Grid.Row="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Hoogte (mm):" Grid.Row="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Gewicht (kg):" Grid.Row="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Serienummer:" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Extra Informatie:" Grid.Row="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Afbeelding:" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Memo:" Grid.Row="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Ingevoerd door:" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="19" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Laatst gewijzigd door:" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="20" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="True" Grid.Row="18" Margin="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="txtMemo" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TabIndex="26" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="True"  Grid.Row="11" Margin="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="txtExtraInfo" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TabIndex="19" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
    <Border Grid.Column="5" Margin="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrushNormal}">
        <Image Name="pbFoto" />
    </Border>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="5" AcceptsTab="False" Grid.Row="9" Margin="1" Name="txtSerial" TabIndex="18" />

    <syncfusion:IntegerTextBox Height="26" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="14" Margin="1" Name="txtL" />
    <syncfusion:IntegerTextBox Height="26" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="15" Margin="1" Name="txtB" />
    <syncfusion:IntegerTextBox Height="26" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="16" Margin="1" Name="txtH" />
    <syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Height="26" NumberDecimalDigits="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="17" Margin="1" Name="txtW" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="False" Grid.Row="10" Margin="1" Name="txtSerie" TabIndex="6" MaxLength="48" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="False" Grid.Row="9" Margin="1" Name="txtModel" TabIndex="5" MaxLength="50" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="False" Grid.Row="8" Margin="1" Name="txtMerk" TabIndex="4" MaxLength="50" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="True" Grid.Row="5" Margin="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="txtDescLong" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TabIndex="3" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="False" Grid.Row="4" Margin="1" Name="txtDescShort" TabIndex="2" MaxLength="48" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AcceptsTab="False" Margin="1" Name="txtNummer" CharacterCasing="Upper" TabIndex="1" MaxLength="25" />
    <Border>
        <Image Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="9" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="1" Name="pbImage" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="220" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <Controls:ToolButton Grid.Column="6" Height="26" Width="26" Source="ISynergy.Resources.Assets.Images.tb_search.xaml" Cursor="Hand" Name="cmdBrowse" />
    <Controls:ToolButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="11" Name="cmdMergeFields" Source="ISynergy.Resources.Assets.Images.tb_search.xaml" Width="26" Height="26" />
    <TextBlock Text="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="19" Name="txtInputFirst" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="20" Name="txtInputLast" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Oppervlakte" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="14"  Name="lblOppervlakte" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Volume" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="15" Name="lblVolume" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Dichtheid" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="16" Name="lblDichtheid" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Controls:ToolButton Name="cmdEditorUitvoering" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Source="ISynergy.Resources.Assets.Images.tb_search.xaml" Width="26" Height="26" />
    <Controls:ToolButton Name="cmdEditorNotitie" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="18" Source="ISynergy.Resources.Assets.Images.tb_search.xaml" Width="26" Height="26" />
    <TextBlock Text="Adres:" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Text="Locatie:" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox Content="Eigen artikel" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="chkIsArtikel" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0,5,0">
        <TextBox Margin="1" Name="txtArtikel" CharacterCasing="Upper" Width="100" />
        <Controls:ToolButton Height="26" Width="26" Source="ISynergy.Resources.Assets.Images.tb_search.xaml" Cursor="Hand" Name="cmdListArtikel" />
        <TextBlock Text="" Name="txtArtikelOmschrijving" />
    </StackPanel>
    <syncfusion:ComboBoxAdv Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="1" Name="selAdres" />
    <syncfusion:ComboBoxAdv Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="1" Name="selLocatie" />
    <TextBlock Text="Staat" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <syncfusion:ComboBoxAdv Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="10" Margin="1" Name="selStaat" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Leverdatum" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="chkLeverDatum" />
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="11" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1" Name="txtLeverDate" />
    <TextBlock Text="Garantie (maanden):" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <syncfusion:IntegerTextBox Height="26" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="12" Margin="1,1,78,1" Name="txtGarantie" />
</Grid>
```

and this is my viewmodel with all inherited parents

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ISynergy.Entities.Relations;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
using ISynergy.Common.Types;
using ISynergy.Library;

namespace ISynergy.Models.Relations.Editors
{
public class ServicingProduct_ViewModel : Base.Base_Relation_Dialog_ViewModel<ISynergy.Entities.Relations.Servicing_Product>
{
    #region "Properties"
    public List<ValuedItem> Product_States { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region "Constructors"
    public ServicingProduct_ViewModel()
        :base()
    {
        Product_States = new List<ValuedItem>();

        Item = new Servicing_Product() { Relation_Id = Relation.Relation_Id };
        IsNew = true;

        using (BusyIndicator = new Busy())
        {
            Initialization = InitializeAsync();
        }
    }

    public ServicingProduct_ViewModel(Servicing_Product e)
        :this()
    {
        Item = e;
        IsNew = false;
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Initializers"
    public async override Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Product_States.Clear();
            Product_States.Add(new ValuedItem(0, StringTable.Onbekend));
            Product_States.Add(new ValuedItem(1, StringTable.ArtikelStaatNieuw));
            Product_States.Add(new ValuedItem(2, StringTable.ArtikelStaatGebruikt));
        });
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Events"
    public async override Task Submit(Servicing_Product e)
    {
        if (IsNew == true)
        {
            await new Url(Current.ApiUrl)
                .AppendPathSegment("servicing_products")
                .WithBasicAuth(Current.Username, Current.Password)
                .PostJsonAsync(e);
        }
        else
        {
            await new Url(Current.ApiUrl)
                .AppendPathSegment("servicing_products")
                .WithBasicAuth(Current.Username, Current.Password)
                .PutJsonAsync(e);
        }

        await Item_Changed();
        await Close();
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

DesignInstance creates an actual instance of your ViewModel.  That means whatever code runs within the ctor of the type is going to run within Visual Studio and the designer.  There is no way to prevent this using DesignInstance, as it is by-design behavior.

You can work around this in a number of ways.

First, don't do any work in your ctor.  If that isn't possible...

Check to see if you're in design mode prior to doing work in your ctor.  That's accomplished via the `GetIsInDesignMode` method.

```
if(System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(
    new DependencyObject()))
    return; // short circuit in design mode
InitializeComponentForRuntimeLol();
```

Some people are allergic of this, for some reason, but if you aren't sneezing it's an option.

If you are sneezing at this, the last option is to create types with the same facade as your VMs, but that don't have any executing code in them.  That means you'll have some random types hanging around that you don't need at runtime.

Anyhow, there isn't a perfect solution as it currently stands.  There have been calls for the ability to use json to define objects for use in binding within the designer, but I don't think that's been acted on in 2015 :/

Comment: Thanks so much for this - solved the problem admirably for me. I had a Design-time View Model that inherited the application's View Model. Unfortunately, the base class VM did some work that couldn't be done at design-time. Adding a guard resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Will's answer is correct that your problem is due to the designer trying to run your viewmodel at design time. Let me offer an alternative solution that doesn't involve making your code IDE-aware.

First, assign the DataContext in the xaml. I usually do it like this, but a variation on your method will probably also work:

```
<WindowClass.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:ViewModel />
</WindowClass.DataContext>
```

Next in the ViewModel, isolate property initializations, which should remain in the constructor, from methods that populate the properties with data. The designer will be able to initialize all the properties, but won't be reliant on the availability of actual data to instantiate the class. It will have a layout like this:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObervableCollection<string> ListOfThings { get; set; }

    ViewModel()
    {
        ListOfThings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public void PopulateData()
    {
        ListOfThings = DataHelperClass.GetData();
    }
}
```

This allows the designer to instantiate your class without having to have access to data or data retrieval classes that are only available at run time.

Finally we call the method to populate data from the constructor of our `page.xaml.cs` code behind. This ensures that it runs on load, but not at design time:

```cs
public partial class WindowClass : Window
{
    ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
    vm.PopulateData();
}
```

If you have multiple controls with their own DataContext, you can just name them with x:Name and then get their view models in the code behind by replacing "this" with the name.

One further note: 
If you're doing this with a WPF UserControl inside of an ElementHost inside a Windows Form like I was, you'll want to put the call to populate data in the constructor of the outer Form.cs so that the designer for the windows form works. You can do it with something like this:

```cs
public FormHost()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)((System.Windows.Controls.UserControl)elementHost1.Child).DataContext;
    vm.PopulateData();
}
```